# Rearrange speed dials in opera without swapping

Tags: opera

How can i rearrange speed dials in opera without swapping? If I drag a speed dial, other speed dials should be moved to right just as if I have inserted it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior in Opera 11.51 – I just tried and it *always* inserts speed dials in their new place.

Comment: Thank you very much, now can I swap speed dials where I need? :)